# HTML to RTF string conversion in VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, rtf, rich-text-editor

I have a jquery Rich Textbox editor (http://jqueryte.com/) which allows the end user to fill in their content to generate a word document report.

The process is as following:

User fills in the content --> Saving the HTML of the Richtext box content into the database. --> Pull the stored HTML content from the database and convert it into an RTF string for it to be opened in Microsoft Word.

I tried converting the HTML to an RTF ( a function that would take in my HTML string and give out the equivalent RTF string) but it was getting too complicated to manipulate all the HTML tags. I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution (except not a free one at least) for the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think jquery rte syntax and word rte syntax are not same.

Comment: Any ideas on how can I achieve the conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the MS Office Word Interop (although frowned upon by some)...

```
string html = "<html><head><style>p{margin:0}</style></head><body style=\"font-family:Arial;\">" + value.Replace("<p>&nbsp;</p>", "<p><br></p>") + "</body></html>";

byte[] htmlBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);

string htmlPath = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".html";
string rtfPath = htmlPath.Replace(".html", ".rtf");

FileStream fs = new FileStream(htmlPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
fs.Write(htmlBytes, 0, htmlBytes.Length);
fs.Close();

Application word = new Application();
Document doc = word.Documents.Open(htmlPath);
doc.SaveAs(rtfPath, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF);
doc.Close();
word.Quit();

fs = new FileStream(rtfPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] rtfBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(rtfBytes, 0, rtfBytes.Length);
fs.Close();

string rtf = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rtfBytes);

Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();

    rtb.Rtf = rtf;

    rtf = rtb.Rtf;
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
return rtf;
```

The reason I have used a RichTextBox as well as Word is that Word's RTF files are extremely bulky... when Word's RTF data is fed into a RichTextBox it filters out all the unneeded code.